# How do I upload my personal NodeJS website to my FTP server?

Tags: node.js, ftp

I need your help. I have my personal NodeJs website for a contact form. Everything works fine on my localhost, but when I put it on my FTP server it didn’t work because the HTML file is in the "public" folder, I can’t get this file out of the folder because otherwise it doesn’t work anymore. So I had a problem transferring my website to the FTP server since my index.html file is in the "public" folder, which I solved by configuring the . htaccess, however, it only loads html but not CSS or JS, what do I do?

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


const PORT = process.env.PORT;

// Middleware
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json())

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
})

app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'mail@gmail.com',
            pass: process.env.NODE_PASS ,
        }
    })

    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.email,
        to: 'mail@gmail.com',
        subject: `Message from ${req.body.name}: ${req.body.email}`,
        text: `${req.body.message}`,
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send('error');
        }else{
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response)
            res.send('success')
        }
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port ${PORT}");
});
```

```
         <form id="myForm">
            <div class="wesh">
              <div class="wallah">
                <div class="field">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="frerot">
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="wallah">
                <div class="field">
                  <label for="mail">Email</label>
                </div>

                <div class="frerot">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wesh">
              <div class="lamif">
                <div class="field">
                  <label for="message">Message</label>
                </div>

                <div class="frerot">
                  <textarea
                    class="contact_textarea"
                    name="message"
                    id="message"
                    rows="5"
                    required
                  ></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="submit_button">
              <button class="submit_cousin" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

```
package.json

{
  "name": "contact-form",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "cross-env node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

[image of my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qwpa.png)

Comment: Can you share what your HTML file looks like? How are you running the Express server?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how I am running it, I just did "$ npm install express --save" and used it by init I guess

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding. node.js is a runtime that execute js on the server side. It run as seperate process on the server, for that you need to start it, like that `node index.js` since you write something about .htaccess i gues you are have allready a apache running. Server the static files (html/ss/js) from apache, and just do the contact handling via node.js. OR, shut apache down and use only node. If node is not installed on the server or you have no ssh access you cant node.

Comment: Yes, you’re right, I’m a beginner in development and rather specialized Front, so I didn’t really understand how to use NodeJS. I don’t have SSH access with my host (OVH). So I will stop using Node and find a solution with PHP, which may be easier in my case. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the extra info.

Your express server is serving just the index.html file out of the `public` folder when you call `GET /`. If you want to be able to serve all the other static files from there using express, you can use the `express.static` middleware. Here are the docs: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

That said, it sounds like you're not actually running/accessing the express server.

> I just did "$ npm install express --save" and used it by init I guess

To run the server, you would have to do `node server.js`.
Also, express wouldn't care about the `.htaccess`. I don't know what kind of server you are using, but it sounds like you are using its existing Apache setup to serve the `public` directory.

This is perfectly fine way to access a static site. You don't need to use express for this.

Also, this wasn't part of your question, but the `from` field is ignored by Google when sending mail this way. They will always come from your own email.

If you don't want to worry about making sure your express server stays online to send emails, you could consider using something like JotForm and embedding it into your app. I believe they have a free tier that you can use.

Comment: `express.static` is used already, isn't it?

Comment: My bad, I had overlooked that piece. I think your `app.get('/', ...)` is overriding `express.static`.

Comment: Yeah, i agree it's overriding but there's a bigger issue I don't think that node is running in that ftp server?

Comment: Yes, you’re right, I’m a beginner in development and rather specialized Front, so I didn’t really understand how to use NodeJS, and actually, my FTP server runs with Apache. And when I run my website in local I have to do "node server.js", which I cannot do on my FTP server.

Comment: I stand by my recommendation then that you should use JotForm for your Contact Me form. For local testing of your site, you can use this: https://github.com/http-party/http-server. You don't have a need to run an express server.

Comment: If you really want to use gmail for your contact form, then you will have to look into how to host an express server. You won't be able to use the FTP server you have now.

Comment: I finally decided to do it in PHP, as I pay for hosting at OVH I had to go through an Apache server and use PHP. As I want to master NodeJS which seems to me much more modern than PHP I will think of taking an Express server for my future projects. Thank you very much for your help anyway!